# Limit of a two variable function

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2}.$$

Does this function have a limit when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

I've tried several paths and I keep getting $0$, so I think the limit is $0$, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Have you tried using polar coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{|x^3+y^3|}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{|x|x^2+|y|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{(|x|+|y|)(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=|x|+|y|\to0$$

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use polar coordinates; if you let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and use $x^2+y^2=r^2$,

you should be able to show the limit is 0.

Answer (score 0):

This form might make it easier to see what is happening:

$\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{x}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}+\dfrac{y}{1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\left|x^3+y^3\right|=\left|(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)\right| \le \frac32 |x+y|(x^2+y^2)$$